# Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve

Tags: equation-solving

while solving the following equations I got the error `Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.`

```
Solve[s1*c2 - s2*c1 + s1 == 0 && 
  s2*c1 - s1*c2 + s2 == 0 && -s1 - s2 == 
   0 && s1^2 + c1^2 == 1 && 
    s2^2 + c2^2 == 1 && -1 <= s1 <= 1 && -1 <= c1 <= 1 && -1 <= s2 <= 
     1 && -1 <= c2 <= 1 && s1 \[Element] Reals && 
    c1 \[Element] Reals && s2 \[Element] Reals && 
    c2 \[Element] Reals, {s1, s2, c1, c2}]
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: *Mathematica* 13.0 solves this. The constraints don't make a difference.

Comment: Note that since you give inequalities as constraints for the variables, you don't need to demand that they are real.

Comment: @JohnDoty I'm using Mathematica 13.0. I just removed the Real constraints but still got the same error..

Comment: Did you try in a fresh session?

Comment: @JohnDoty Yes I restarted Mathematica and tried again. Strange..

Comment: *Mathematica* 12.1 solves this.  Copy/paste from the question into a fresh session.